# Numpy: split array based on groups that satisfy condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to split a numpy array into chunks that obey a certain condition. For example, given `a = np.array([ 1,  2,  3,  4, 10,  9,  8,  7,  7,  7,  8,  9, 10])` return `[array([3, 4]), array([7, 7, 7])]` since those chunks obey the condition `np.logical_and(a>2,a<8)`.

The solution I came up with works, but it feels awkward since I'm applying the condition first to split the array and then again to select the results I want.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([ 1,  2,  3,  4, 10,  9,  8,  7,  7,  7,  8,  9, 10])
cond = np.logical_and(a>2,a<8)
splits = np.split(a,np.where(np.diff(cond))[0]+1)
# this yields [array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([10,  9,  8]), array([7, 7, 7]), array([ 8,  9, 10])]
result = [x for x in splits if np.logical_and(x>2,x<8).any()]
# [array([3, 4]), array([7, 7, 7])]
```

Is there a way to apply the same condition to both so that if I wanted to change the condition I could change it once in my code instead of twice? Or am I over-complicating things where there's a much simpler, more pythonic, way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one option, *subset the array before split to eliminate the for loop*:

```
cond = (a > 2) & (a < 8)
np.split(a[cond], np.where(np.diff(np.where(cond)[0]) > 1)[0] + 1)
# [array([3, 4]), array([7, 7, 7])]
```

Comment: That's clever. I forgot that `np.where` returns an array of indices exactly the same size as the subset so that the original breaks are preserved in the subset by jumps in the indices greater than 1. Thanks!